# How to load multiple coding standards in phpcs

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, phpcs

How could load multiple coding standards in phpcs?

While sniffing the files, I am supposed to use an xml file which uses three coding standards.

When I try to set their paths one by one, only recent one gets stored and old standard gets replaced.

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../wordpress-coding-standards;

phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../wordpress-coding-standards/PHPCompatibility;
```

I also tried setting this value up with parent directory but it didn't work.
Here's the final command which throws the errors:

```
phpcs -p -s -v  -n --standard=phpcs.xml /path/to/files
```

This is the xml file which is being used in above command:
https://github.com/xwp/wp-dev-lib/blob/master/phpcs.xml

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by specifying multiple paths separated by commas.

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths first/path/,second/path/,yet/another/path/
```